# How to use UrlToBe in selenium for only part of the URL

Tags: google-chrome, selenium, selenium-chromedriver, webautomation

I have a requirement two requirements in Selenium Chrome driver automation using .net.

1. Waiting for particular base URL to load. For that I got the below code which works perfectly if I gave the exact URL,

```
wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.UrlToBe("https://accounts.google.com/ServiceLogin?service=mail&passive=true&rm=false&continue=https://mail.google.com/mail/&ss=1&scc=1&ltmpl=default&ltmplcache=2&emr=1&osid=1#identifier"))
```

but I dont want to give the exact URL, instead I want to give base URL since the most of the URL's are dynamically generated with some IDs. So here in my case I want to match https://accounts.google.com,

2. I want to get a event before the URL is going to change (when user clicks on some button for example next). or I want to get notified when user has entered  the username or some entries in the webpage.

My complete requirement is as follows,

For the first time user will enter username, date of birth manually in the automated window. Now my requirement is when user opens my application for next time I want to enter the name and D.O.B using code.

Previously I was using Internet Explorer and there I had beforenavigate event which will inform me that user is going navigating to other URL. So I used to read the required fields and save it in my database.

How to do this in Selenium or Chrome driver ?

WebElement.getAttribute('value') can be used to get the value, but how to know that user has entered the values to that field ?

How can I achieve these 2 ?
Please help me.

Comment: you can put an `isEmpty()` check on the `value` `getAttribute`...wouldn't that help to confirm if the user has entered it or not. Probably when exactly has user done that could be checked using a `listener`. But it seems to be a not so good practice to have manual interaction in between.

Comment: @nullpointer can you please explain with an example ?

Answer (score 1):

***Case 1*** : You can't possibly override the `UrlToBe` method from `org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions.java`, it being a `static` method. Documented [here](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/master/java/client/src/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/ExpectedConditions.java#L101).

But what you can try and do is create a similar class and custom method which could be something like `CustomExpectedConditions.java`

```
//you provide the base Url here
public boolean UrlContains(String subsetUrl) {
  private String currentUrl = driver.getCurrentUrl();
  return currentUrl != null && currentUrl.contains(subsetUrl);
}
```

***Case 2*** : If you want to track the url pre-actions considering the actions to be click(), clear() etc on a `WebElement` from the list [here](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebElement.html). You can override these methods in a `CustomWebDriver` class extending the `WebDriver` and implementing `WebElement` interface something like :

```
public class CustomWebDriver extends Webdriver implements WebElement {

  @Override
  public void clear() {
    //  save the Url before performing the ops
  }
  // ...similarly for other actions
}
```

Comment: my intention is to get the username entered by user in automated window. Is there any method to watch the username field and copy the content before URL changes.

Comment: @ITresearcher : I am expecting it to be static field unless an action is triggered, can't you save it before an action. Also if not, please update the same in the question, would look into the details for specific case.

Comment: edited the question. I not getting how to know user has entered something.

Comment: can you please explain with an example ?

Answer (score 0):

Since [Jun 04, 2015](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-support/2.46.0) in Selenium 2.46.0, I believe we've had [urlMatches()](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/ExpectedConditions.html#urlMatches(java.lang.String)) that takes a regex string, that can be a partial. This at least answers the question in the name and is why I came here. I use urlMatches for a wait until the url changes into a certain path, instead of my own solution.